# Dynamic "add to basket" link on html email

Tags: html, email, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm an email designer and I've recently seen something that I think is rather impressive but I have no idea how this company have done it.

Basically, they have links on their email that adds products directly into the user's basket (on their website). I've never seen this kind of functionality before. I'm guessing they've got some clever re-directing going on but I really don't know.

A link to the email is here: http://tinyurl.com/ose5m22

Do you know how they've done it?

Cheers! Paul

Comment: just use links with get params. where is the problem?

Comment: It's not so much a problem, I'm just a HTML and CSS kinda guy and was wondering how it was done is all...

Answer (score 1):

It's not an "email" feature. The button is just a link to a website and the link got parameters to initialize a basket.

Comment: I knew this wouldn't be a html email code situation but I'm just a html and css kinda guy - would this be a php job for it to work? Sorry to ask the obvious (if it is obvious)

Comment: Yes it is a server-side job (php, java, python, C#, whatever).